# I want to remove all rows which turn out the result "unknown" for a certain column

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, rows

I'm new to programming and to Python3/Pandas.

I have written a csv file to a dF and am using pandas and numpty. The dF contains a series of columns, A, B, C, etc. and several thousand rows of data for them (not all numerical). I want to remove all instances of "unknown" from the data frame.

I have tried:

dF = dF[dF['A' != 'unknown']]

but it gives me an error message.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error in your question?

Answer (score 2):

You means this?

```
df = df[df['A'] != 'unknown']
```

Or you can use `query()`:

```
df = df.query('A != "unknown"')
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. If I need to filter rows based on a date range (I have 1 column containing dates in datetime format, how would I do it?

Comment: You can use `&` to connect conditions: `df = df.query('A != "unknown" & B > "2017-09-21"')`

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work, but I get the warning "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"

Answer (score 2):

You need filter data by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','unknown','b'],
                   'B':pd.date_range('2017-01-01', periods=3),
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5]})
print (df)
         A          B  C  D
0        a 2017-01-01  7  1
1  unknown 2017-01-02  8  3
2        b 2017-01-03  9  5
```

You need to enclose multiple conditions in braces due to operator precedence and use the bitwise and (`&`) and or (`|`) operators if multiple conditions:

```
df1 = df[(df['A'] != 'unknown') & (df['B'] > '2017-01-02')]
print (df1)
   A          B  C  D
2  b 2017-01-03  9  5
```

But if need processes data later:

```
df1['C'] = df1['C'] + 1
print (df1)
```

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
>   Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Problem is if you modify values in `df1` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`df`) and that Pandas does warning.

Solution is [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
df1 = df[(df['A'] != 'unknown') & (df['B'] > '2017-01-02')].copy()
print (df1)
   A          B  C  D
2  b 2017-01-03  9  5

df1['C'] = df1['C'] + 1
print (df1)
   A          B  C  D
2  b 2017-01-03 10  5
```